# Not able to send logs to /var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log file and not able to mongod is forked and run as a daemon

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[image]I am doing the course M103 from MongoDB University. They're having a lab section that we need to solve. I am stuck with Chapter 1: The Mongod
Lab: Logging to a Different Facility

Update your configuration file such that:

1)mongod sends logs to /var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log
2)mongod is forked and run as a daemon (this will not work without specifying logpath)

anyone can please explain to me the detailed procedure. I am getting an error while solving it.

Comment: Stop the mongod daemon and start mongo service manually with `mongod`, then you see log messages which should give a hint for your problem

Comment: I am getting an error like "ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option."

Comment: What are these "additional information in this output"? Did you try without --fork as advised in the error message?

Comment: i started without  --fork it runs successfully. output is like ...log file "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" exists; moved to "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.

Comment: How to launch mongod with the logpath ? and how to modify my mongod configuration to fork the process?

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html

Comment: Finally able to solve after a lot of efforts.. @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for your valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. mongod --logpath /var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log
2. mongod --config mongod.conf
3. Login with the user in order to validate your work

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run in the shell the following line:

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log --config mongod.conf
```

- `--logpath /var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log` to set the log file
- `--fork` to run a mongod process as a daemon (i.e. fork)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the previously given answers, you can simply add this to the conf file:

...

```
systemLog:
  path: "/var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log"
  destination: "file"
processManagement:
  fork: true"
```

And then execute

> mongod --f mongod.conf